# Importing a number of modules at once

Tags: haskell

I have a number of modules under the same folder:

```
/src/Web/MyLib/Types/Entity1.hs
/src/Web/MyLib/Types/Entity2.hs
/src/Web/MyLib/Types/Entity3.hs

...
```

Most of them require importing the same modules such as `Data.Time, UUID` and others. Instead of importing those models to **each** of the modules under `/src/Web/MyLib/Types/`, is there any way to create one **base** module, say, `/src/Web/MyLib/Types/Base.hs`, import all those modules (`Data.Time, UUID, ...`) to it and then only import `Base` to `EntityX`? I've tried it and failed. Maybe I did something wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an example, taken from `Control.Lens`, which achieves what you want: it imports everything in a base module and re-exports everything.

```
module Control.Lens
  ( module Control.Lens.At
  , module Control.Lens.Cons
  , module Control.Lens.Each
  -- ...
  ) where

import Control.Lens.At
import Control.Lens.Cons
import Control.Lens.Each
-- ...
```

Comment: I'm confused, which part of that "imports" and which "re-exports"?

Comment: @imatahi `import` imports, and whatever is between the parentheses in `module Name ( ... )` is exported. If you export a module, everything which was imported from it is re-exported.

Comment: Okay, But still I can't figure out how to apply that for my case.

Comment: `module OneBase
  ( module Data.Time
  , module UUID
  ) where

import Data.Time
import UUID`